# Date difference using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: android

I want to get how many hours using AM/PM, but I can only get the hours without using AM/PM

This is my code

```
 private TextView textView,textView1,txtdiff;

String dateStart = "03/13/17 08:30:00";
String dateStop = "03/13/17 05:30:00";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_date_view);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondDate);
    txtdiff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.difference);

    textView.setText("First Date: "+ dateStart);
    textView1.setText("Second Date: "+ dateStop);
}

public void getCurrentDate(View view) {

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;

    try {
        d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
        d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

        long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

        long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        String seconds = Long.toString(diffSeconds);
        String minutes = Long.toString(diffMinutes);
        String hours = Long.toString(diffHours);
        String days = Long.toString(diffDays);

        txtdiff.setText(hours + " Hours");



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The problem is that I want to add AM PM.

I have tried adding the strings with AM and PM

```
String dateStart = "03/13/17 08:30:00 am";
String dateStop = "03/13/17 05:30:00 pm";
```

and using the SimpleDate format:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
```

but unfortunately it does not work, can anybody point me to the right direction

Comment: `but unfortunately it does not work` how exactly?

Comment: @VladMatvienko it just shows 0 Hours in the textView sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use small 'hh' when you define your hour format

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
```

Otherwise your values ara considered as beeing defined using 24h format and 08 and 05 will be both in the morning even if you have specified am/pm

Comment: I am such an idiot haha. Thanks bro! I could kiss you. Thank you very much Sir

Comment: @david, it's not mandatory to kiss him, just mark answer as a correct (accept answer). That's actually a great note to notice such a weird thing in date format.